# How can I get an array of field values for each instance of the Class?

Tags: matlab, oop

I have an array of classes with fields, e.g.:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        field = 1;
    end
end
...
myClassArray = [];
for i = 1 : 100
    myclass = MyClass;
    myClassArray = [myClassArray myclass];
end
```

I need to have an array of field values for each instance of the MyClass. I can do it this way:

```
fields = zeros(length(myClassArray ), 1);
for i = 1 : length(myClassArray )
    fields(i) = myClassArray(i).field;
end
```

But this code looks cumbersome. If I try do it this way:

```
fields = myClassArray.field;
```

, the value of fields variable is this: fields==myClassArray(1).field;

How can I get an array of field values for each instance of the MyClass less cumbersome way?

Comment: What about `fields = {myClassArray.field}` or `[myClassArray.field]`?

Comment: It's work, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
fieldValues = [myClassArray.fieldName]
```

or if you want a cell array

```
fieldValues = {myClassArray.fieldName}
```

As a side note, I wouldn't call a variable `fields`.